# IF/ else statements and Operators

Tags: javascript

I working on a form but I have some troubles with the last if statement ( it's not working.

`count` is global and start as `0`, for each field with the correct character filled in this will happen: `count = count+1;`

but if I clicked submit and leave 2 fields with not the correct character

( that should be `count = 6` ) it doesn't give me an alert but skips it

this is how it should be.

1. check if password equals confirm_password
2. check if fields or not empty
3. check if fields have the correct characters ( count start as count = 0 , foreach field that is correct it it goes count = count +1,
   in totaal it can get 8 but at 6 it still keeps submitting).

```js
function validateForm() {

  var fields = ["voornaam", "achternaam", "Email", "Wachtwoord", "Herhaal_Wachtwoord", "Straatnaam", "Huisnummer", "Postcode", "Woonplaats", "Telefoonummer"];

  if (pass1.value !== pass2.value) {
    alert("Wachtwoord komen niet overeen");
    return false;
  }
  
  var l = fields.length;
  var fieldname;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldname = fields[i];
    if (document.forms["register"][fieldname].value === "") {
      alert(fieldname + " can not be empty");
      return false;
    }
  }

  if (count < 8) {
    alert("iets is niet goed ingevuld");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: don't use `return` before `alert`.

Comment: Your username? And why are you so fast?

Comment: Beat me to it Fast Snail, thought I was first.

Comment: Would probably be quicker to specify which fields do NOT require mandatory validation in your array, then loop through all the fields in the form, checking their type and if they exist in the array, skip that validation for that input.

Answer (score 1):

You have returned the `false` boolean before you have given the **alert** prompt! Just change the last `if` statement like this:

```
if (count < 8) {
    alert("iets is niet goed ingevuld");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if (count < 8) {
    alert("iets is niet goed ingevuld");
    return false;
} ,      this didnt work for me